# SQL Server 2012 - Frequent SELECT and UPDATE on bit column. Index doesn't help

Tags: sql-server, performance, index, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server table with about 2 million rows in, this table stores short textual documents. Here's my schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Documents (
    documentId bigint IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    content nvarchar(MAX) NOT NULL,
    isIndexed bit NOT NULL
)
```

I have a separate Lucene-based indexer process that does this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 documentId, content FROM Documents WHERE isIndexed = 0
```

It then performs the indexing operation before executing this:

```
UPDATE Documents SET isIndexed = 1 WHERE documentId = @documentId
```

Initially this worked fine. When every document in the table was not indexed (i.e. all `isIndexed` values were 0) then each retrieval took about 5ms.

However as more and more documents were indexed then the retrieval time slowly increased. Currently it's about 150ms - a 30 time speed reduction. I note that the UPDATE statement always seems to run in under 2ms, so I know that's not a problem.

From the start the table has always had a non-clustered index on the isIndexed column, but the Actual Execution Plan shows the SQL Server uses an Index Scan (rather than Seek).

What can I do to speed up the system?

I am aware that the "isIndexed" column existing is bad in itself, but due to how the indexer works it can't request documents by documentId directly. For this and other reasons I can't accept any answers that don't solve the immediate problem at hand.

Comment: This is a bit aside: you could very likely speed up the indexing process by grabbing more than one row at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table (now) has the following non-clustered indexes:

```
IX_Indexed_ASC (Non-Unique) ( IsIndexed ASC, DocumentId ASC )
IX_Indexed_DESC (Non-Unique) ( IsIndexed DESC, DocumentId ASC )
IX_IsIndexed_Filtered (Non-Unique) ( DocumentId ASC WHERE IsIndexed = 0 )
IX_DocumentId_Indexed (Unique) ( DocumentId ASC, IsIndexed ASC )
```

And the clustered index:

```
PK_Documents ( DocumentId ASC )
```

I changed my query from this:

```
SELECT
    TOP 1 DocumentId,
    Content,
    IsIndexed
FROM
    Documents
WHERE
    IsIndexed = 0
```

to this:

```
SELECT 
    DocumentId,
    Content,
    IsIndexed

FROM
    Documents
WHERE
    DocumentId = (
        SELECT
            TOP 1 DocumentId
        FROM
            Documents
        WHERE
            IsIndexed = 0
    )
```

And now the queries execute in under 10ms again. The Actual Execution Plan reports that it's performing two index seek operations on IX_Indexed_ASC and IX_DocumentId_Indexed.

Comment: Is `Threads` a typo?  Or a real table?

Comment: Sorry, a typo. It's "Documents".

Comment: Still don't understand why all your `TOP 1` queries don't have an `ORDER BY`. Do you really not care which arbitrary row you get? Why not use `MIN` or `MAX` instead of `TOP 1`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand (With apologies for responding 8 years too late) - I didn't have an `ORDER BY` because my application did not care *which* single row was returned.

Answer (score 5):

An index on the bit column isn't going to help at all because of selectivity. You should consider a filtered index:

```
CREATE INDEX unindexed ON dbo.Documents(documentId) WHERE IsIndexed = 0;
```

You should also include an `ORDER BY documentId` in your `SELECT`.

Though you should test this in a staging environment because it may help your `SELECT` but may offset that with a more expensive `UPDATE`.

Comment: I added the filtered index using your suggestion, but there wasn't any speedup with my existing queries. I did find an alternative solution which I've posted below.